# Better way to handle Repeating Notifications other than UILocalNotification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I've been reading a lot about UILocalNotification, and I've also added some to my App.
My problem is that I want a repeating notification (every 2 minutes for example) but I don't want them 'stacking up' if the user is not responding to each one as they appear.
There doesn't seem to be any way to handle this - apparently, notifications are meant to be responded every time by the user and are not meant to be ignored.

So, is there a better way to notify the user when the app is in the background, or is a local notification the only method?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried any of this code, but you can cancel your previously sent `UILocalNotification` and send another one.

```
if(_lastSentNotification) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:_lastSentNotification];
}
_lastSentNotification = ...code to create UILocalNotification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:_lastSentNotification];
```

With respect to `cancelLocalNotification`, the API Documentation says:

> Calling this method also programmatically dismisses the notification if it is currently displaying an alert.

So it sounds like you don't necessarily have to have user interaction to handle the notification.

Comment: Thanks but I believe the problem is that notifications stack up while in the background, and the above code can't run while in the background, so you can only kill notifications after the user taps View and the app returns to the foreground...

Answer (score 1):

How about only scheduling notification N+1 while you're handling notification N, after the user has responded to it?

Comment: That'll only work if the user responds - the problem is when they don't respond the notices stack up, and you can only respond to the user tapping "View" which opens the app.

Comment: Right, if user doesn't respond, new ones don't get scheduled.  If user does respond, new ones do get scheduled.  Thought that's what you wanted, but I guess I misunderstood.

Comment: If the user taps 'close' each time the notices shows, there's no problem. However, if the user is away from their device for a while, the notices stack up and they have to tap 'close' many times in a row - that's the issue. If they tap "view", it's no problem - the app opens and I don't need notifications unless they close it again...